# Kusto query, join tables to display computer domain

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, azure-monitoring, kql

We have a query that displays the top 5 computers with eventlog errors/warnings:

```
Event
| where EventLevelName has_any ("Error","Warning")
| summarize count() by Computer
| top 5 by count_
```

We are collecting logs from multiple customers, so i would like to have a column that shows the computer domain aswell.

Is it possible to use another table and match computer names? Like "Heartbeat" table and the columns "Computer"/"Tenantid"

I guess i would need to use somthing like:
`union Event, workspace("xxxxx").Heartbeat`
As this would get the correct tenantid..

Since eventlogs are sent directly to our tenant, the table "Event" only contains a single Tenantid

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/lookupoperator) or [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) operators, if it does not work please provide a sample of the two tables.